# Multiplying matrices with MPI (segmentation fault)

Tags: matrix, segmentation-fault, mpi

I've recently started learning MPI and, as you may have guessed, I have already encountered an error I can't solve on my own!

I want to write a program that will multiply two matrices. However **I haven't got that far**, in fact, I'm stuck on broadcasting the matrices in the first place.

```
#define MASTER 0
if (rank == MASTER) {
        A = (double *) malloc(N * N * sizeof(double));
        B = (double *) malloc(N * N * sizeof(double));
        matFillRand(N, A);
        matFillRand(N, B);
    }

if (rank == MASTER) {
        P = (double *) malloc(N * N * sizeof(double));
    }

matMulMPI(N, A, B, P);

if (rank == MASTER) {
        printMatrix(N, P);
}
```

The functions that (in theory) does the math is as follows:

```
void matMulMPI(long N, double *a, double *b, double *c) {
    long i, j, k;   
    int rank, size;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    MPI_Bcast(&N, 1, MPI_LONG, MASTER, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Bcast(b, N*N, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    printMatrix(N, b);

    //TO-DO: Broadcast A
    //TO-DO: Do Math
}
```

And this broadcast doesn't work. I get the following message:

> *** Process received signal**  Signal: Segmentation fault (11) Signal code: Invalid permissions (2) Failing at address: 0x401560 Signal:
>   Segmentation fault (11) Signal code: Invalid permissions (2) Failing
>   at address: 0x401560 [ 0]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10340) [0x7fc3ede6b340] [ 1]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x981c0) [0x7fc3edb2e1c0] [ 2]
>   /usr/lib/libmpi.so.1(opal_convertor_unpack+0x105) [0x7fc3ee1788d5] [
>   3]
>   /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_pml_ob1.so(mca_pml_ob1_recv_frag_callback_match+0x460)
>   [0x7fc3e6587630] [ 4]
>   /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_btl_sm.so(mca_btl_sm_component_progress+0x487)
>   [0x7fc3e572a137] [ 5] /usr/lib/libmpi.so.1(opal_progress+0x5a)
>   [0x7fc3ee1849ea] [ 6]
>   /usr/lib/libmpi.so.1(ompi_request_default_wait+0x16d) [0x7fc3ee0d1c0d]
>   [ 7]
>   /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_tuned.so(ompi_coll_tuned_bcast_intra_generic+0x49e)
>   [0x7fc3e486da9e] [ 8]
>   /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_tuned.so(ompi_coll_tuned_bcast_intra_binomial+0xb7)
>   [0x7fc3e486df27] [ 9]
>   /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_tuned.so(ompi_coll_tuned_bcast_intra_dec_fixed+0xcc)
>   [0x7fc3e486573c] [10]
>   /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_sync.so(mca_coll_sync_bcast+0x64)
>   [0x7fc3e4a7d6a4] [11] /usr/lib/libmpi.so.1(MPI_Bcast+0x13d)
>   [0x7fc3ee0df78d] [12] ./matMul() [0x4011a9] [13] ./matMul() [0x401458]
>   [14] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)
>   [0x7fc3edab7ec5] [15] ./matMul() [0x400b49]
>    **End of error message**  [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10340) [0x7fa4a1fe5340] [ 1]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x981c0) [0x7fa4a1ca81c0] [ 2]
>   /usr/lib/libmpi.so.1(opal_convertor_unpack+0x105) [0x7fa4a22f28d5] [
>   3]
>   /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_pml_ob1.so(mca_pml_ob1_recv_frag_callback_match+0x460)
>   [0x7fa49a701630] [ 4]
>   /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_btl_sm.so(mca_btl_sm_component_progress+0x487)
>   [0x7fa4998a4137] [ 5] /usr/lib/libmpi.so.1(opal_progress+0x5a)
>   [0x7fa4a22fe9ea] [ 6]
>   /usr/lib/libmpi.so.1(ompi_request_default_wait+0x16d) [0x7fa4a224bc0d]
>   [ 7]
>   /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_tuned.so(ompi_coll_tuned_bcast_intra_generic+0x4e0)
>   [0x7fa4989e7ae0] [ 8]
>   /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_tuned.so(ompi_coll_tuned_bcast_intra_binomial+0xb7)
>   [0x7fa4989e7f27] [ 9]
>   /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_tuned.so(ompi_coll_tuned_bcast_intra_dec_fixed+0xcc)
>   [0x7fa4989df73c] [10]
>   /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_sync.so(mca_coll_sync_bcast+0x64)
>   [0x7fa498bf76a4] [11] /usr/lib/libmpi.so.1(MPI_Bcast+0x13d)
>   [0x7fa4a225978d] [12] ./matMul() [0x4011a9] [13] ./matMul() [0x401458]
>   [14] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)
>   [0x7fa4a1c31ec5] [15] ./matMul() [0x400b49]
>    **End of error message ***
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------- mpirun noticed that process rank 2 with PID 12466 on node
>   rtidev5.etf.bg.ac.rs exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------- 2 total processes killed (some possibly by mpirun during cleanup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out. All processes (not only the master) need to allocate memory first.

So the missing line was

```
void matMulMPI(long N, double *a, double *b, double *c) {
    ...

    MPI_Bcast(&N, 1, MPI_LONG, MASTER, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    b = (double *) malloc(N * N * sizeof(double));

    MPI_Bcast(b, N*N, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    ...
}
```

Comment: And just to clarify why this is the case: a broadcast means that every process after the broadcast will be storing data in the first argument to `MPI_Bcast`. On the master process, it's a send buffer, but on the other processes it's a receive buffer. Regardless, you will attempt to store data in a non-allocated buffer if it's not allocated on every process before calling `MPI_Bcast`.